# Fat Free sample example failing

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to run the very simple fat free example with no success,

**index.php:**

```
<?php
        $f3=require('fatfree/lib/base.php');
        $f3->route('GET /',
            function() {
                echo 'Hello, world!';
            }
        );
        $f3->run();
?>
```

**.htaccess content:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

**Error Log:**

```
[Fri Dec 21 20:50:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] - /var/www/html/index.php:2 require('/var/www/html/fatfree/lib/base.php')
[Fri Dec 21 20:50:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: ONERROR' in /var/www/html/fatfree/lib/base.php:1252
Stack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/fatfree/lib/base.php(790): Base->{closure}(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/html/f...', 790, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/fatfree/lib/base.php(1246): Base->error(500, 'date_default_ti...', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Base->{closure}(Object(ErrorException))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/fatfree/lib/base.php on line 1252
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and looking in my /var/log/httpd/error_log i noticed i just had to set timezone. I found out 2 ways to do so:
1) just call date_default_timezone_set() function at the beginning of your index.php file like this:

```
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome'); //That's my timezone, choose the right one
    $f3=require('fatfree/lib/base.php');
    $f3->route('GET /',
        function() {
            echo 'Hello, world!';
        }
    );
    $f3->run();
    ?>
```

but imho that's not a great solution. I prefer the next one:
2) Locate your php.ini file (inside /etc/ in my Fedora 17) and modify those lines:

```
    [Date]
    ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
    ; http://php.net/date.timezone
    ;date.timezone =
```

like this:

```
    [Date]
    ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
    ; http://php.net/date.timezone
    date.timezone = 'Europe/Rome'
```

save and then restart httpd service with

```
    sudo service httpd restart
```

I hope it helps :D